# Attached: curriculum vitae to french

Tags: moderncv, cv

I'm trying to write a cv and a related letter in french. But, I'm getting on the bottom of the letter this text in english:

[image]

How do I to make it appear in french ? The only setting that I'm using is this :

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,french]{moderncv}
```

Is there something wrong with this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
\enclosure[Annexe]{curriculum vit\ae{}} % List of enclosed documents
```

instead of:

```
\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}} % List of enclosed documents
```

(not sure if "Annexe" is the right word)